# How can I make my JQuery calendar hide weekends and past dates at the same time?

Tags: jquery

My code

```
<label for="">Fecha de atención:</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="datepicker" ></input>

    <script>
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
          beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            return [(day != 0 && day != 6)];

      }
    });
  </script>
```

OK, so I have this input with ID datepicker and under there, the script to hide weekends, but what I want to do is hide past dates but I can't unfortunately and also it would be great if the datepicker can also hide special dates like xmas or new year eve.

Also I want to change the format to day-month-year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the weekends covered, but with certain properties and other handling the rest can be achieved!

To hide past dates:

```
minDate: -10 // Hide dates more than 10 days ago
```

For the desired date format:

```
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' // Set the desired date format
```

Handling to skip certain days:

```
let skipDays = ['2019-12-25', '2019-12-31']; // Dates to skip
let fullDate = '' + date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();

                                  // fullDate not found in skipDays
return [(day != 0 && day != 6) && skipDays.indexOf(fullDate) == -1];
```

Put all that together within your code:

```
<label for="">Fecha de atención:</label>
<input class="form-control" id="datepicker"></input>

<script>
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: -10,           // Hide dates more than 10 days ago. 
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', // Set the desired date format
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();

        // Handling to skip certain days
        let skipDays = ['2019-12-25', '2019-12-31']; // Dates to skip
        let fullDate = '' + date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();

                                          // fullDate not found in skipDays
        return [(day != 0 && day != 6) && skipDays.indexOf(fullDate) == -1];
    }
});
</script>
```

The datepicker output will look like this:

[image]

...and here's a runnable example:

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
 minDate: -10,  // Hide dates more than 10 days ago. 
 dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', // Set the desired date format
 beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var day = date.getDay();

            let skipDays = ['2019-12-25', '2019-12-31']; // Dates to skip
            let fullDate = '' + date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();

                                          // fullDate not found in skipDays
            return [(day != 0 && day != 6) && skipDays.indexOf(fullDate) == -1];
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<label for="">Fecha de atención:</label>
<input class="form-control" id="datepicker"></input>
```